# Robocopy script /w Powershell + Mail report for failure

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, robocopy

I'm studying for Network\System Admin certification (MCSE is in it) and among other things we started to delve into powershell scripting.

At any rate my instructor gave me a challenge to do as follows:
I need to create a PS script which will run Robocopy tool in order to mirror a folder from point A to Point B and that script should run as a schedule task (/w Task Scheduler).
If robocopy have encountered any errors the script should send a mail via the Company's exchange mail server to the Admin in charge of the process.

I'm not Scripting savvy of any sort so I had to sit and learn the syntax, command etc before I could start working.

Here is what I got so far:

```
# PowerShell Robocopy Script V.1 | Liron Ben-David 

# Variables
$Source ="C:\Source\"
$Destination = "C:\Destination\"
$ExitCode = "Null"

#Copying Process
Robocopy $Source $destination *.* /mir /r:100 /w:10

# Return Code Section
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {$ExitCode = "Succeeded, Code: $LASTEXITCODE" }
elseif (($LASTEXITCODE -gt 1) -and ($LASTEXITCODE -lt 17)) {$ExitCode = "Failure, Code: $LASTEXITCODE" }
else {$ExitCode = "No Return Code"}

Write-Host $ExitCode

## Failure Report
if ($ExitCode -gt 1) {Send-MailMessage -to "Admin (Admin@Domain.com)" -From "Machine-Robocopy1 (M1RC@domain.com)" -Subject $ExitCode -SmtpServer mail.domain.com}
else {exit}
```

basically if there is any kind of error in the process the script supposed to send an email with the script error code as the "Subject" of the message.

First of all:
Does this script contain any embarassing mistakes I did and which I should avoid in the future?

Secondarily:
I never used the CLI to send email messages, using the Send-Mail CMDLET I should have used a credentials switch but according to what I've read\watched it seems it will pop up a window for input.
Considering I'm setting this script for a Domain Environment wouldn't the SSO feature will kick in when I try to send the message?

EDIT:
Also noticed I mixed the error codes so I need to re-calibrate the error code lines.

EDIT 2: Version 2 bsaed on your help,

```
# PowerShell Robocopy Script V.2 | Liron Ben-David 

# Variables
$Source = "C:\Source\"
$Destination = "C:\Destination\"
$ExitCode = "Null"
$ReturnCodeValue = "Void"
$Log = "C:\RoboLogs\RobocopyLog.txt"

#Copying Process
Robocopy $Source $destination *.* /mir /r:100 /w:10 /UniLog:C:\RoboLogs\RobocopyLog.txt /v

# Return Code Section
if (($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) -or ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 1) -or ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 3) -or ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 5) -or ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 6) -or ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 7)) {$ExitCode = "Succeeded, Code: $LASTEXITCODE" }
elseif (($LASTEXITCODE -eq 2) -or ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 4)) {$ExitCode = "Error, Code: $LASTEXITCODE" }
elseif ($LASTEXITCODE -gt 7) {$ExitCode = "Failure, Code: $LASTEXITCODE" }
else {$ExitCode = "No Return Code"}

$ReturnCodeValue = $LASTEXITCODE

# Debug Section
#Write-Host "Did the script completed succesfuly:" $?
#Write-Host "Script Exit Code:" $ExitCode
#Start-Sleep -s 4


## Failure Report
if (($ReturnCodeValue -gt 7) -or ($ReturnCodeValue -eq 2) -or ($ReturnCodeValue -eq 4)) {Send-MailMessage -to "Admin (Admin@Domain.com)" -From "Machine-Robocopy1 (M1RC@domain.com)" -Subject $ExitCode -SmtpServer mail.domain.com –Attachments $Log -UseSsl}
else {exit}
```

Comment: To your first question, you are setting `$exitcode` to a string and then comparing if against an integer. PS will convert the 1 into a string and then compare the two strings lexographically. I haven't used `Send-MailMessage` but since it is specifying an SMTP server, I'd guess it depends on the SMTP server. First whether it requires credentials at all, and second whether it support SSO.

Comment: So on ## Failure Report section I can use $LASTEXITCODE insdead of $ExitCode and that's should fix that, correct?

Comment: Not sure what an exit code -ge 17 means, but as long as it means failure or isn't possible, then I'd say yes. Remember that `$LASTEXITCODE` is an automatic variable so it will get updated whenever you run an external program. So if are using it more than a few lines away from where it is set, it is probably a good idea to save it, like: `$roboExitcode = $lastexitcode` and then use `$roboExitcode`.

Comment: good idea! I'll try that out. the `lt` switch means "Lesser Then", if you check the return codes the highest one is 16. But if it doesn't get 0 to 8 or 16 it means no value was entered - > hence robocopy didn't ran at all. So I might need to adjust it to "Different from" the list of available return codes instead.

Comment: As it stands, the email you're sending isn't going to be particularly useful. Consider using the logging option in RoboCopy, and attaching the log to the email.

Comment: You mean something like "If there is an error" then "Produce Log file" and "send it to Admin" ? it was my next stage of planning. I need to test an efficient way to analyze which files were not copies or which parts of the process were failed then make use of it.

Comment: You're relying on the exit code to tell you there's been an error. You can't decide you wanted a log file after the fact.

Comment: I'm working on it right now, I'm creating the log in the `#Copying Process` section and the log is overwriting itself each time. Then if there is an error the log will be attached to the mail message.

Comment: Ok gents, how does it look now? (note there is actually a credential option for a domain in robocopy):  ^^^ check out main post edit.

Comment: I've updated the post again it seems I don't need credentials when using `Send-MailMessage` to an Exchange server it will use the active session to authenticate.

Comment: my only advise here would be to be aware of how large that log file could get. I have done something similar but instead sent a Link in the message via UNC based path instead of attaching to avoid a 30mb message failing.

Comment: Better than someone telling you how it looks, suggest you report how it works.

Comment: Good point on the attachment size. I'll change that @ssaviers, thanks.